# Firebase App: Google Analytics very limited

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics

I just connected my Firebase App to Google Analytics.
The problem is, that Google Analytics shows just the same Information as the Firebase Analytics Tab.
Google Analytics is very limited for my App in general. Like I can not customize the dashboard, view realtime data, etc.
How can I access all Google Analytics Features for a Firebase App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to implement the Google Analytics SDK or a better solution would be to implement the Google Tag Manager SDK and use Firebase as your data layer that you pass into Google Analytics.

Here is Google documentation how to do this for iOS: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5/

Here is Google documentation how to do this for Android:
https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/